# Application setting not work

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have Micromax canvas gold a300 and its application setting not work when I try to open it show setting unfortunately stopped.
So I cant open application setting on my mobile phone.  Please help me

Comment: Are you rooted?  Have you tried a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it may be a fault in Micromax's firmware. I suffered from the same issue on a Canvas Fire. Do a backup and a full wipe. If issue persists, contact your nearest service center or try installing a stable custom ROM.